# How to configure wcf service to accept compressed requests

Tags: wcf, compression, iis-7.5

I have a WCF service running on iis7.5 that accepts data from a simple win forms client. The response from the server to the client is pretty small (a success or failure), but the request posted contains a lot of data.

Can I configure the service to accept a compressed request? The examples I've seen show how to compress the response and how a client can indicate that it can handle the compression, but how do you compress traffic in the other direction?